# How do rubble pile asteroids form?

Tags: solar-system, asteroids

This Dr. Becky video describes the early history of the solar system. [Why the Earth exists because of Saturn | Migration of Planets](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cPouwOKMS2s&t=994s).

In it she talks about how a cloud of nanometer to centimeter sized debris slowly clumped into kilometer sized planetesimals. Computer simulations show a runaway collision process built up planets from there. A short simulation is shown about 2 minutes in. And right away I have questions.

It appears the asteroids are separated by roughly 20x their diameter. Is this realistic? Did the early solar system have enough material to make a disk that dense?

If not, how did a runaway collision process work? Two asteroids nearly on a collision course do not collide. The smaller one is flung away by a gravitational slingshot.

Are these collisions violent or gentle? You can see what looks like both in the simulation. In later stages, violent near collisions are how the Oort cloud formed. The large planets pretty much cleaned out the solar system this way. I would think early stages must have had its share of violent near misses and collisions. Violent collisions would break apart planetesimals.

But many asteroids today are rubble piles. The majority of asteroids in the [JPL Small-Body Satellites](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/sb/sats.html) page are binaries. See [What is the smallest known gravitationally bound system?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/787333/37364). This implies that these asteroids never experienced a violent collision. Instead they were build from a series of gentle collisions. Given escape velocities of a few meters per second, they must have been very gentle.

So how did this work, given that asteroids that fly by Earth do so at kilometers per second?

---

From g s's comment, triboelectricity is important. Interesting. I would not have guessed that

The Wikipedia article [Triboelectric effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triboelectric_effect) has a reference to this paywalled paper. [The Growth Mechanisms of Macroscopic Bodies in Protoplanetary Disks](https://www.annualreviews.org/doi/pdf/10.1146/annurev.astro.46.060407.145152)

The abstract says

> The formation of planetesimals, the kilometer-sized planetary
> precursors, is still a puzzling process. Considerable progress has
> been made over the past years in the physical description of the first
> stages of planetesimal formation, owing to extensive laboratory work.
> This review examines the experimental achievements and puts them into
> the context of the dust processes in protoplanetary disks. It has
> become clear that planetesimal formation starts with the growth of
> fractal dust aggregates, followed by compaction processes. As the
> dust-aggregate sizes increase, the mean collision velocity also
> increases, leading to the stalling of the growth and possibly to
> fragmentation, once the dust aggregates have reached decimeter sizes.
> A multitude of hypotheses for the further growth have been proposed,
> such as very sticky materials, secondary collision processes, enhanced
> growth at the snow line, or cumulative dust effects with gravitational
> instability. We will also critically review these ideas.

So I guess it is still an open question.

Comment: Afaik triboelectricity and van der Waals forces, plus energy dissipation as heat from collisions and tidal force interactions, are the missing pieces of the puzzle.

Comment: E.g. if you smash two asteroids together, you can't just measure the temperature of the pieces and expect the rest of the starting kinetic and gravitational energy to stay kinetic and gravitational energy; the collision will have had a tribocharging effect, so there's now an electric potential energy term sharing the energy budget as well.